# UNIX cant read MyBatis resource file

Tags: java, spring, unix, mybatis, ibatis

On Windows, my MyBatis queries and Java JAR is working perfectly fine.
But when I deploy it on UNIX environment , the program does nothing when I make call to mybatis queries.
Through logging statements, the programs becomes silent here:

```
    LOGGER.info("MyBatisUtil() BEGIN..");
    try(Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("main/resources/mybatis-config.xml")){
        sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);
        LOGGER.info("successful, reached his part..");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

This part appears on my logfile ->  `LOGGER.info("MyBatisUtil() BEGIN..");`

This part DOES NOT appear on my logfile ->  `LOGGER.info("successful, reached his part..");`
So I am assuming that UNIX cant read my mybatis config file.
How can I tell UNIX to properly read my mybatis config file?

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
  PUBLIC '-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN'
  'http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd'>
<configuration>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
            <transactionManager type="JDBC" />
            <dataSource type="POOLED">
                <property name="driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="url" value="MY_URL_THIS_IS_FINE/postgres" />
                <property name="username" value="user" />
                <property name="password" value="pass" />
            </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="mybatis-mapper/mybatismapper.xml" />   
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

Again. This JAR file is PROPERLY WORKING on Windows. Unix env is the problem.

Comment: The code may be throwing an `Error` (e.g. "class not defined"), not an `Exception`. Change `} catch (IOException e) {` to `} catch (Throwable e) {` and try again to see if you see the error.

Comment: Also, what flavor & version of unix are you using?

Comment: What are the file permissions?